# Paper clip image showing up in wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

Hey i have a rails app that i am uploading images with paperclip....

So i have a comic_review scaffold that i upload images of comic covers and i also have a news scaffold where i post news and images.....

When i edit news/1/edit and upload a picture the comics_review/1 picture becomes the same as the news one and vice a versa.

I checked the links in the views to make sure that i is correct and they seem to be ok...

heres my view

home.html.erb

```
          <h2 style="color: black; font-size: 30px;"><%= @comic_review1.title %></h2>
          <p><%= @comic_review1.content %></p>
          <%= link_to 'Read More...', comic_review_path(@comic_review1) %>               
          <%= image_tag @comic_review1.photo, class: "homepage_comics" %>
```

news/show.html

```
          <%= @news.author %>
          <%= @news.date %>
          <%= image_tag @news.photo, class: 'pull-left', style: 'margin-right: 10px;' %>
```

heres my controller

static_pages_controller.rb

```
           class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
           def home
         @user = current_user
             @article = Article.first
             @comic_review1 = ComicReview.find(1)
             @comic_review2 = ComicReview.find(2)
             @comic_review3 = ComicReview.find(3)
             @comic_review4 = ComicReview.find(4)
           end

           def comics
             @comic_review1 = ComicReview.find(1)
             @comic_review2 = ComicReview.find(2)
             @comic_review3 = ComicReview.find(3)
             @comic_review4 = ComicReview.find(4)
           end

           def batnews
             @article = Article.first
             @news_all = News.all
           end
           end
```

heres my model

comic_review.rb

```
        class ComicReview < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :content, :credits, :review, :title, :photo, :comicreview
        has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => '400x400' },
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
        :path => ":attachment/activities/:id/:style.:extension",
        :bucket => 'goddam_batman_pics'

        has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
        end
```

news.rb

```
        class News < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :title, :author, :date, :content, :photo
        has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => '400x400' },
       :storage => :s3,
       :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
       :path => ":attachment/activities/:id/:style.:extension",
       :bucket => 'goddam_batman_pics'
       end
```

controllers are your basic controllers that gets generated by the scaffold

so whenever i update a photo for news/1 the photo for comic_reviews/1 gets the same photo as the news one

any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're giving the "photo" the same name in both models.  Try naming one comic_photo and the other news_photo, or alternately, explore Polymorphic Associations.

Dated Railscast link, but gives you the idea - http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

PS - Bonus points for figuring out how to load four ComicReviews in one query rather than four in those controllers.

Comment: thats a good point ill give that a shot i went over the polymorphic association stuff when creating comments.....but i also have an article modle and i'm using photo as well it seems to not have any problems

Comment: Try a different `:path` for the two different models?

Comment: i dont think it has anything to do with the 'photo' name since they are both different tables right?  so if i had a table called something1 with a field of name and another table with something2 with a field of name it should be unique for each table

Comment: so i guess it has something to do with amazon s3 i removed the code for that and everything is normal

Comment: im not to sure how to change the path for that though

Answer (score 0):

ok so what i had to do was in my model i changed the path from

:path => ":attachment/activities/:id/:style.:extension",

to

:path => "/image/:id/:filename",

and it seems to be working